# How can I analyze console output data from a triggered jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 jobs 'job1' and 'job2'. I will be triggering 'job2' from 'job1'. I need to get the console output of the 'job1' build which triggered 'job2' and want to process it in 'job2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part is to find out the build number of the upstream job (`job1`) that triggered the downstream job (`job2`). Once you have it, you can access the console log, e.g. via `${BUILD_URL}consoleOutput`, as pointed out by ivoruJavaBoy.

How can a downstream build determine by what job and build number it has been triggered? This is surprisingly difficult in Jenkins:

Solution A ("explicit" approach): use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to "manually" pass a build number parameter from `job1` to `job2`. Apart from the administrational overhead, there is one bigger drawback with that approach: `job1` and `job2` will no longer run asynchronously; there will be *exactly* one run of `job2` for *each* run of `job1`. If `job2` is slower than `job1`, then you need to plan your resources to avoid builds of `job2` piling up in the queue.

So, some solution "B" will be better, where you extract the *implicit* upstream information from Jenkins' internal data. You can use Groovy for that; a simpler approch may be to use the [Job Exporter Plugin](http://Job%20Exporter%20Plugin) in `job2`. That plugin will create a "properties" (text) file in the workspace of a `job2` build. That file contains two entries that contain exactly the information that you're looking for:

```
build.upstream.number   Number of upstream job that triggered this job. Only filled if the build was triggered by an upstream project.
build.upstream.project  Upstream project that triggered this job.
```

Read that file, then use the information to read the console log via the URL above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Post Build Task plugin, then you can get the console output with a wget command:

```
wget -O console-output.log ${BUILD_URL}consoleOutput
```

Comment: I am planning to trigger it through a python file

Comment: You have several ways to do this.. i just like to avoid to download and use new plugin if you don't really need them... Python could be good choice, also write a ruby script in the Jenkins job.. i just would avoid any use a not useful plugin, also the copy artifact plugin could help you, standard one.. :)